# How to write Lambda with generic typed parameter without raw types

Tags: java, generics, lambda, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have a class Foo with a generic type parameter

```
static class Foo<T> {

    T get() {return null;}

    void set(T t) {}

}
```

I want to define an instance of java.util.function.Consumer that works for ANY Foo regardless of its generic type argument. The consumer will simply call the set method on the Foo instance and pass in the value returned by the get method. I decided to use a Lambda to implement the consumer:

```
Consumer<Foo> compilesButWithWarnings = foo -> foo.set(foo.get());
```

Unfortunately I get warnings with this implementation. The warning is:

```
The method set(Object) belongs to the raw type Foo. 
References to generic type Foo<T> should be parameterized.
```

If I attempt to write my lambda as:

```
Consumer<Foo<?>> compileError = foo -> foo.set(foo.get());
```

the code would no longer compile giving me the error:

```
The method set(capture#1-of ?) in the type Foo<capture#1-of ?> is not 
applicable for the arguments (capture#2-of ?)
```

The one solution I could come up with which compiles without warnings is this:

```
Consumer<Foo<?>> worksButRequiresStaticMethod = Test::setFoo;

static <ANY> void setFoo(Foo<ANY> foo) {
    foo.set(foo.get());
}
```

which is okay for now but a little verbose. If at all possible I would like to know if there is a better way to write this code without warnings and without changing Foo.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Cant define an instance that works with any generic type. The generic type must be known for that particular instance and is part of its statically typed signature by the compiler.

This will work:

```
Consumer<Foo<Object>> c = (Foo<Object> o) -> o.set(o.get());
```

That is an instance for that particular generic parameter value (Object).

You need another “instance” for every separate type.

Makes sense?

It is like asking for a variable that is of any type.

A variable only has one type. Known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to use a generic method that provides you with the consumer instance.

For instance:

```
static class Foo<T> {
    T get() {return null;}
    void set(T t) {}
}
public static <T>Consumer<Foo<T>> getFooConsumer() {
    return foo -> foo.set(foo.get());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Consumer<Foo<String>> cons = getFooConsumer();
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();
    foo.set("foo!");
    cons.accept(foo);
}
```

Note that since your consumer code implementation presently doesn't really do much useful, it's hard to tell if this workaround will be any help depending on your real requirements.

You could always push it further, and inject a value of your choice into your consumed `Foo`, for instance:

```
public static <T>Consumer<Foo<T>> getFooConsumer(T t) {
    return foo -> foo.set(t);
}
```

Comment: That is another option but I don't think it is any realy improvement. The code I provided in my question is of course a very basic simplification. My real use case is much bigger and more complicated. I guess the cleanest approach would be to simply create a new class file instead of putting more code inside lambdas.

Comment: @DudeDoesThings I had a feeling it was much more complex yeah. If you're somehow able to summarize the use case despite it being more complex, you can always update your question (and let me know, I might take another look). Btw you don't need to accept my answer only because it's the only answer around - someone (including myself) might have something better in time - I'd unaccept if I were you.

Comment: When I asked the question I thought that maybe some feature I never heard anything about before may have come up now with java 9 and java 10. When I learned java it was still during the java 7 time. But as it seems there is no "clean" solution to this. So I thought I might as well select your answer as having solved the problem. I simply accept that it can not be solved to the extent that I have been wishing for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit `Foo`, you can add a method to handle this internally:

```
void update() {
    set(get());
}
```

Then just use that method as the consumer:

```
Consumer<Foo<?>> consumer = Foo::update;
```

Otherwise, I think the static method is the only way. You need to avoid having the  `<?>` wildcard type at the point where `set` is called, since the only thing you can pass to an unbounded wildcard method parameter is `null`.